# What is "Composite Command Prompt" in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

"Composite Command Prompt" shows up as a menu item in Windows 8, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation about what it is. When I run it, I get an instance of cmd.exe. So, what is it?

Comment: Never heard of it myself, and don't have Windows 8 handy right now to check, my _guess_ is it's from a 3rd party program.  If you right-click and check the properties of the shortcut, what is it pointing at?

Comment: can you turn its background transparent? if so, its cmd with 3D compositing in its UI rendering. with standard command prompts you cannot enable any kind of transparency. just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd told people in your question what folder in the Start menu you'd found this in, there wouldn't be such perplexity.  My educated guess is that you found it in the `Programs > Autodesk > Autodesk Composite` folder of your Start menu.

It's not unusual for development software packages to add Start menu items that simply invoke the command interpreter with a lot of extra environment variables and whatnot already set up, so that one can run various command-line tools from the package more easily.  Visual Studio 2010 has a [`Visual Studio Command Prompt` item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx) on the Start menu, for example.  (It's still there in VS2012.)

This is just more of the same, except that it sets up the environment and whatnot for [running python scripts for **Autodesk Composite**](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2014scripting-composite/autodesk_toxik-module.html), previously known as Autodesk Toxik, and runs a command interpreter from which one can invoke said scripts.  Hence "Composite".

Of course, the clue to what it is *is* right there in the Start menu, staring one in the face as the name of the folder containing the shortcut.  Don't forget to tell people this important where-you-found-it information next time.  We're not clairvoyant you know.  ☺